# make touch when file requested

Tags: linux, apache

is there a way to configure apache to change file last modified date when a file is requested ?
I want to do this for images, so when image is requested I want file last modified date to be changed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: make a shell script that is called when a file is requested i think is possible but not for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
touch -m
```

> "-m option changes only the modification time"

Add (test.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
`touch -m /var/www/cgi-bin/test1.txt`
```

to script in the cgi directory

```
 chmod 755  /var/www/cgi-bin/test.sh
```

And hit your httpd cgi

http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.sh

All the best

Comment: if I understand script correctly it will "touch" test1.txt each time file is requested. Is there a way to touch requested file ?

Comment: Hi User3061583 If you give me an example. I'll try and help you with a script

Comment: Hi User3061583  Eg are the files known and in a directory?

Comment: Hi Pnorton, yes files are known. I have a lot of images in a directory and each time image is requested I want to update modification time of this image which was requested. This is done to remove unused images. At the end of month another script will remove all images which modification time is older than this month. Thank you for your help